# When should we assign a value to a new variable?

Tags: php, performance, variables

Given the following code:

```
AND (myTable.field_1 IN ('" . implode("','", $myObj->userStatus) . "')
  OR myTable.field_2 IN ('" . implode("','", $myObj->userStatus) . "')
  OR myTable.field_3 IN ('" . implode("','", $myObj->userStatus) . "'))";
```

What is the BEST practice and WHY:

1) Use as it is. (Ugly for reading but does NOT create a new variable that will be read-only).
2) Make it better for reading and maintain creating a variable to hold that value and do like so:

```
$userStatus = $myObj->userStatus;
//Some Code HEre

AND (myTable.field_1 IN ('" . implode("','", $userStatus) . "')
  OR myTable.field_2 IN ('" . implode("','", $userStatus) . "')
  OR myTable.field_3 IN ('" . implode("','", $userStatus) . "'))";
```

Is there any "down side" for creating a variable in this case? Or it does not impact performance so we should take the "nice to read" path?

Comment: DRY: `$userStatus = implode("','", $myObj->userStatus);`

Answer (score 3):

First, you can precompute the `implode("','", $userStatus)` into a variable. This way, you don't have to repeat the implode function multiple times. It's both more readable and has better performance.

Second, the most important thing is that you are dealing with your data in the wrong way! this kind of computations should be done in your database. For example, you have converted the many-to-many relation into a one-to-many. This has made your code less readable and less efficient.

Third, don't over-engineer your code. If you are making an operation, do it in a variable to be more readable rather than more performant. Performance is **usually** dependent on algorithm, structure, and design not by defining variables.

Answer (score 1):

As a *general* practice, I don't assign a new variable unless I'm actually going to use it in a way that requires it.  There are of course exceptions to this, where readability would be significantly improved.  I don't think your example meets that threshold at all.

In fact, I think your specific example, assigning another variable here makes it potentially unclear what `$userStatus` is.  It's another thing to keep track of when skimming through code.

Certainly, there's nothing "ugly" about `$myObj->userStatus`.

In any case, there are other problems here.  You should never concatenate data directly into an SQL query.  It requires escaping at a minimum, but binding parameters is better.  Otherwise, you're opening yourself up to a whole host of bugs and security issues.

If you used named parameters, you'd find you would only use `$myObj->userStatus` once anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following code :

```
$userStatus = $myObj->userStatus;
//Some Code HEre

$userStatusimp = implode(',', $userStatus);

AND (myTable.field_1 IN ('" .$userStatusimp. "')
  OR myTable.field_2 IN ('" .$userStatusimp . "')
  OR myTable.field_3 IN ('" .$userStatusimp. "'))";
```

Answer (score -2):

The second way is the way to go. Much better to read and if you need to change something its easier to maintain.

I cant say something fact based on the performance, but i think that option 1) will work a little faster but as long as you dont work on really high performing  projects the difference should not be important.